# Straight forward example using CryptoAPI Next Generation (CNG) to encrypt data

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, aes, cng

I'd like to implement data encryption and decryption in a C++ application running on Windows. I've spent considerable time looking around the Web and am thinking I should probably use the [Windows Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG) functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal) (although I'm open to better alternatives).

What I find everywhere are complex examples that do all sorts of stuff. I don't feel that confident in this area and so I'd like to find a simple example. In the end, I need a method that takes a string and encrypts, and another methods that decrypts the data back to the string. The user would supply a password for both operations.

This must have been done countless times already. Can anyone point me to a complete and competent example? Ultimately, I'll end up with an `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` method.

Something that is both secure and performant would be ideal.

Comment: There's literally an example program off of that link you gave. 
 What is it that you don't understand?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/encrypting-data-with-cng

Comment: @selbie: Yes, I guess so. But it seems to be doing more than just an encryption and decryption function. Also, I was hoping someone could comment on the choice to use this approach with respect to security and performance.

Comment: I'd also recommend you at least learn some of the fundamentals of encryption and cryptography.  Namely algorithms, key sizes of each, block sizes of each algorithm, chaining and initialization vectors. It's not hard to learn this stuff.  But once you do learn the fundamentals, the Windows API is much easier to grok. But for what it's worth, OpenSSL APIs are much easier and portable to accomplish the same tasks as they are in Windows. The classic book: https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Cryptography-Protocols-Algorithms-Source/dp/1119096723/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before encrypting (and decrypting) you need to derive key from password with key derivation functions (for example [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) with SHA256). To prevent pre-computed dictionary attacks
in additional to password you will also need random string (called salt).
Next pick cipher algorithm ([AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with 256-bit key is good one) and [cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) (ECB cipher mode considered weak, so use any other for example CBC). Also it will require one more random string (called initialization vector).

So encrypting algorithm will be:

1. Generate random salt
2. Derive key(password, salt) = key
3. Generate random IV
4. Encrypt(key, IV, plain text) = cipher text

Input parameters: plain text, password
Output parameters: cipher text, salt, IV

Decrypting algorithm will be:

1. Derive key(password, salt) = key
2. Decrypt(key, iv, cipher text) = plain text
   Input parameters: cipher text, salt, iv, password
   Output parameters: plain text

Sample code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt")

static NTSTATUS gen_random(BYTE* buf, ULONG buf_len)
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg = nullptr;
    NTSTATUS status = NTE_FAIL;
    do {
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, L"RNG", nullptr, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            return status;
        }
        status = BCryptGenRandom(hAlg, buf, buf_len, 0);
    } while (0);
    if (hAlg) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
    }
    return status;
}

static NTSTATUS derive_key(BYTE* pass, ULONG pass_len, BYTE* salt,
                           ULONG salt_len, const ULONG iteration, BYTE* derived_key, ULONG derived_key_len)
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hPrf = nullptr;
    NTSTATUS status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    do {
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hPrf, L"SHA256", nullptr, BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC_FLAG);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
        status = BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2(hPrf, pass, pass_len, salt, salt_len, iteration, derived_key, derived_key_len, 0);
    } while (0);
    if (hPrf) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hPrf, 0);
    }
    return status;
}

static NTSTATUS do_encrypt(BYTE* key, ULONG key_len, BYTE* plain_text, ULONG plain_text_len,
                           std::vector<BYTE>& iv, std::vector<BYTE>& cipher_text)
{
    NTSTATUS status = NTE_FAIL;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg = nullptr;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = nullptr;
    do {
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, L"AES", nullptr, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* create key object */
        status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlg, &hKey, nullptr, 0, key, key_len, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* set chaining mode */
        std::wstring mode = BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC;
        BYTE* ptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(const_cast<wchar_t*>(mode.data()));
        ULONG size = static_cast<ULONG>(sizeof(wchar_t) * (mode.size() + 1));
        status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, ptr, size, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* generate iv */
        ULONG block_len = 0;
        ULONG res = 0;
        status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&block_len), sizeof(block_len), &res, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
        iv.resize(block_len);
        status = gen_random(iv.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(iv.size()));
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* BCryptEncrypt modify iv parameter, so we need to make copy */
        std::vector<BYTE> iv_copy = iv;

        /* get cipher text length */
        ULONG cipher_text_len = 0;
        status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, plain_text, plain_text_len, nullptr, iv_copy.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(iv_copy.size()),
                               nullptr, cipher_text_len, &cipher_text_len, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
        cipher_text.resize(static_cast<size_t>(cipher_text_len));

        /* now encrypt */
        status = BCryptEncrypt(hKey, plain_text, plain_text_len, nullptr, iv_copy.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(iv_copy.size()),
                               cipher_text.data(), cipher_text_len, &cipher_text_len, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING);
    } while (0);
    /* cleanup */
    if (hKey) {
        BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    }
    if (hAlg) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
    }
    return status;
}

static NTSTATUS do_decrypt(BYTE* key, ULONG key_len, BYTE* cipher_text, ULONG cipher_text_len,
                           const std::vector<BYTE>& iv, std::vector<BYTE>& plain_text)
{
    NTSTATUS status = NTE_FAIL;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg = nullptr;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = nullptr;
    do {
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, L"AES", nullptr, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* create key object */
        status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlg, &hKey, nullptr, 0, key, key_len, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* set chaining mode */
        std::wstring mode = BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC;
        BYTE* ptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(const_cast<wchar_t*>(mode.data()));
        ULONG size = static_cast<ULONG>(sizeof(wchar_t) * (mode.size() + 1));
        status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, ptr, size, 0);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }

        /* BCryptEncrypt modify iv parameter, so we need to make copy */
        std::vector<BYTE> iv_copy = iv;

        /* get expected plain text length */
        ULONG plain_text_len = 0;
        status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, cipher_text, cipher_text_len, nullptr, iv_copy.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(iv_copy.size()),
                               nullptr, plain_text_len, &plain_text_len, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING);
        plain_text.resize(static_cast<size_t>(plain_text_len));

        /* decrypt */
        status = BCryptDecrypt(hKey, cipher_text, cipher_text_len, nullptr, iv_copy.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(iv_copy.size()),
                               plain_text.data(), plain_text_len, &plain_text_len, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING);
        /* actualize size */
        plain_text.resize(static_cast<size_t>(plain_text_len));
    } while (0);
    /* cleanup */
    if (hKey) {
        BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    }
    if (hAlg) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
    }
    return status;
}


NTSTATUS encrypt(BYTE* pass, ULONG pass_len, const std::vector<BYTE>& plain_text,
                 std::vector<BYTE>& salt, std::vector<BYTE>& iv, std::vector<BYTE>& cipher_text)
{
    NTSTATUS status = NTE_FAIL;
    salt.resize(8);
    std::array<BYTE, 32> key{0x00};
    do {
        /* generate salt */
        status = gen_random(salt.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(salt.size()));
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
        /* derive key from password using SHA256 algorithm and 20000 iteration */
        status = derive_key(pass, pass_len, salt.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(salt.size()), 20000, key.data(), key.size());
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
        /* encrypt */
        status = do_encrypt(key.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(key.size()), const_cast<BYTE*>(plain_text.data()),
                            static_cast<ULONG>(plain_text.size()), iv, cipher_text);
    } while (0);
    SecureZeroMemory(key.data(), key.size());
    return status;
}


NTSTATUS decrypt(BYTE* pass, ULONG pass_len, const std::vector<BYTE>& salt, const std::vector<BYTE>& iv,
                 const std::vector<BYTE>& cipher_text, std::vector<BYTE>& plain_text)
{
    NTSTATUS status = NTE_FAIL;
    std::array<BYTE, 32> key{0x00};
    do {
        /* derive key from password using same algorithm, salt and iteraion count */
        status = derive_key(pass, pass_len, const_cast<BYTE*>(salt.data()), static_cast<ULONG>(salt.size()),
                            20000, key.data(), key.size());
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            break;
        }
        /* decrypt */
        status = do_decrypt(key.data(), static_cast<ULONG>(key.size()), const_cast<BYTE*>(cipher_text.data()),
        static_cast<ULONG>(cipher_text.size()), iv, plain_text);
    } while (0);
    SecureZeroMemory(key.data(), key.size());
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the performance characteristics of this approach?

Comment: I'm getting some syntax errors, mostly related to `key`. Also, I see the password is a `BYTE*`. Did you do some conversion, or is this simply a `BYTE` pointer to the original Unicode password string?

Comment: Also, can I ask what is the purpose of your `do` loops with `while(0)`? Why a loop?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood perfomance - Do you mean how much kb/sec data encrypt? Sorry, I didn't benchmarked it.
key - what errors? password - yes it is just pointer to buffer with UTF8 string. do while(0) - it is just Goto analog. You can wrap all BCrypt* functions in a class with BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider in destructor.

Comment: @JonathanWood The loop in this case is basically a goto statement. The break just skips the rest of the instructions in case of failure and goes directly to clean up. It would be no different than doing `goto cleanup` `cleanup: //code here` but it does look cleaner than goto I suppose. goto isn't necessarily bad it's just people tend not to use it properly. In the case of cleanup its perfectly fine similar to a do while (0)

Comment: I too am getting quite a few errors when put into Visual Studio 2022, even with ISO C++ 20.

Comment: @JeffR fixed error in do_decrypt() function call

Comment: @plstryagain Do you have a sample to add IV and SALT to the cipher_text so the code can be run from a DLL and called at different times?

Answer (score -1):

How to use CryptoAPI Next Generation (CNG): Don't use it. Use OTP.

If your user is physically sent the key, then use the simple but unbreakable OTP or One Time Pad (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

It is very easy to use.

It is very easy to understand.

Simply supply enough OTP keys to the user, which you or someone randomly types in via a keyboard (I told you it is easy), to last for what you think is a reasonable use by the user.

Do NOT derive the keys from passwords or from anything else that the previous posters listed. That is lazy and is NOT secure. Make the keys as I said and then they will NOT be linked to any code source at all.

Do NOT waste your time with "learn some of the fundamentals of encryption and cryptography" (if that learning is not directly in support of your using One Time Pads).

For you to read some discussions and definitions related to OTP's:
https://www.slideshare.net/AsadAli108/3-l4
https://www.slideshare.net/Jonlitan/one-time-pad-encryption-technique

There is no commonly known encryption that even comes close to OTPs. Example: OTPs can not be mathematically or computationally broken down into a mathematical or computational process.

I think that you have asked for simple, and easy, and not so complicated, but secure, and One Time Pads are all that. If you supply the keys to the user directly, then no human (other than Christians with enough faith) can break them.

Some links to help you with hopefully useful independent examples in C and C++:

A quick search gave me these examples which due to the limit on time for this bounty I have not tested:

https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-one-time-pad-algorithm/

and

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/179981/

and

https://github.com/DDomjosa/One-time-pad-encryption/blob/master/One%20time%20pad%20encryption.cpp

ps: In case you are wondering why I post but do not reply to comments: My browser does not seem to support the "add a comment" on these Stack Overflow pages, so I can post but I cannot (until SO makes their pages backward compatible sufficient for me) reply or comment beyond that.

Comment: The user must be able to protect their data with a password that only they know.